# Help me choosing a 3d modelling software for this project?

Tags: 3d

I'm making a video where I want to show a few scenarios of a game in 3d:

It has some objects with simple shapes - stairs, walls, barrels. So all I have to do is to model those simple objects and apply the proper textures on the right faces. I have never learned a 3d modelling software so I would like to know, what of them is more suited to this task?

If possible, it would be even better if I could just do it with scripts (python?). For instance, I could make a script that returns the vertex/faces and let the program calculate the model. This would be great as I could get the geometries really fast and then just configure the textures. I'm not really a fan of modelling with the mouse, I always get lost with so many views and stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com) is probably the most accessible for people who don't have "real" 3D experience.

Especially so if your shapes are mostly just boxes. It's a couple click/drags.

If you're looking for a format that you'd be easily able to edit or script, you should check out the [OBJ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). It's a plain-text format that is dead-simple to understand.

Comment: +1: Sketchup is awesome. It has some great videos to get you up and running, too.

Comment: Not for Sketchup, but for pointing out the OBJ format, it's really great!